# Getting regex failure after some time

Tags: java, regex

I have a particular regular expression which fails after about 15-20 days.The regex I have used is:

```
^[^-\\s][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[[a-zA-Z0-9 !_|,ÄÖÜäöüß€:;\'~`\\?$%^*{}()=/@./#&amp;&gt;&lt;+-]+.*\\r\\n]+$
```

The conditions are: To allow only numbers and alphabets in the first word. Anything can follow. It can't be only spaces. Allows German characters as well. All special characters allowed.

I get the below error on log:

```
Stack trace: java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3694)
java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Pos.match(Pattern.java:4965)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3694)
java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
java.util.regex.Pattern$Begin.match(Pattern.java:3472)
java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1221)
java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:559)
java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:1130)
```

Comment: It seems overly complicated. Usually a sign of 'go back to the drawing board and reconsider other options'. Apart from that, what do you mean by 'fails after 15-20 days'?

Comment: I do not know the syntax from java, but are you sure you understand the `[...]`

Comment: It normally doesnt fail. works for all the criteria mentioned . But after around 15 days of usage it fails. Something termed as catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Can someone please provide a simpler regex for the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression could be simplified to `(?ums)^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ [^ ]+$`

Explanation:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` -> started with symbols: a-zA-Z0-9
- - space as delimiter between words
- `[^ ]+` - any symbol except the space

Flags:

- `u` - allow unicode symbols
- `m` - multiline
- `s` - dotall mode (matches any character, including a line terminator)

Tests:

```
public void testRegExp() {
    String regex = "(?ums)^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ [^ ]+$";
    Assert.assertTrue("iuy98 ÄÖ\r\nÜäöüß7".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertTrue("iuy 98ÄÖÜäöüß7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse("iuy98Ä ÖÜäöü\r\nß7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse("i u y98ÄÖÜäöüß7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse("  iuy98ÄÖÜäöüß7*&^&%*$&\r\n".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse("00uy98ÄÖÜä öüß7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse("00uy98ÄÖÜä öüß7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertFalse("$%^&00uy98ÄÖÜä öüß7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertTrue("00uy98 ÄÖÜ____äöüß\r\n7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertTrue("00uy98 ÄÖÜ____äöüß\r\n7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
    Assert.assertTrue("00 uy98{}[]ÄÖÜ____äöüß\r\n7*&^&%*$&".matches(regex));
}
```

Comment: I tried it . doesnt work for all test cases. Can you please suggest something else .

Comment: @shubbi could you please provide test cases to check

Answer (score 0):

> To allow only numbers and alphabets in the first word. Anything can follow. It can't be only spaces.

This one should do the job:

```
^[a-zA-z0-9]+\\S+$
```

Where `\S` stands for any nonspace character.

Comment: @shubbi: Where are your test cases? Edit your question and show some that don't work.